# STM3 USART+DMA not receiving

Tags: stm32, cortex-m, hal, nucleo

I've been learning how to program stm32's and I've come across an issue which I can't seem to debug on my own. Basically, I want to receive 3 bytes over UART and have them stored into memory using DMA. Any help would be greatly appreciated.The exact mode is the one on the nucleo-f401RE

```
  #include "main.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart2_tx;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
uint8_t dataArrived =0;

int main(void)
{

HAL_Init();


  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_Delay(500);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_Delay(500);

  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();  //enable clock to dma

  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  HAL_UART_Init(&huart2);


  hdma_usart2_tx.Instance  = DMA1_Stream5;
  hdma_usart2_tx.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_4;
  hdma_usart2_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
  hdma_usart2_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
  hdma_usart2_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
  hdma_usart2_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
  hdma_usart2_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
  hdma_usart2_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
  hdma_usart2_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
  HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_usart2_tx);

  __HAL_LINKDMA(&huart2,hdmarx,hdma_usart2_tx);

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Stream5_IRQn,0,0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Stream5_IRQn);

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART2_IRQn,0,0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART2_IRQn);

  uint8_t data[3];
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2, &data, 3);

  while(!dataArrived); //Wait for the arrival of data from UART
  /* Infinite loop */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  while(1);

}

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart){
    dataArrived = 1;
}

void DMA1_Stream5_IRQHandler(void){
    HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(&hdma_usart2_tx);
}
```

Basically what the code should be doing is waiting for three bytes to be received and turn an led on. The clock for the USART is enabled in hal_msp as well as the configuration of the pins, which are correct since I used CubeMX to generate that code.

Answer (score 1):

dataArrived has to be `volatile` otherwise the compiler do not see any normal program flow path leading to the variable change and optimizes it out.

Always if you use variables which are changed outside normal program flow they have to be volatile to let compiler know that they are side effects prone.

It is important of course is any level optimization is used.

Comment: Just to add that this may not be evident if compiler optimisation is disabled, which is commonly the default.  The OP's own answer suggests that this wasn't the cause of their immediate problem, but it will certainly be the cause of other problems down the line if not fixed first!

Comment: @cooperised - yes tight. But as you see OP did not even bother to write something, except the own answer. IMO whole question should be removed as it has zero value for the readers

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had the wrong dma stream. I was using stream6 which is for Tx rather than stream5 which is for Rx...noob mistake :/

Comment: so remove this question as it does not have anyt value for anyone